# Single Select dropdown with images in Angular JS

Tags: html, css, angularjs

I don't have much idea about Angular JS so please bear with me if I go wrong with the way I ask this. What we need is a single select dropdown menu which can have images as well. I want the dropdown to be customisable in the sense that the border colour and the background colour of the button that shows the dropdown menu can be transparent. Currently we are using [typeahead](https://github.com/Siyfion/angular-typeahead) but we do not want the keyboard to show when tapping on the input field.

Again, I apologise for the horrible way this question has been asked. I am an iOS developer asking this on behalf of one of my colleagues. Any library you can point me towards would be highly helpful.

Comment: try angular-ui-bootstrap: https://angular-ui.github.io/bootstrap/

Comment: The dropdown thingy?

Comment: yes, you can customize the dropdown template